# Filter by $in and boolean

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I want to obtain documents (products in this case) using find() with two filters, the first one is **state = true** and the second one is if the product belong to a category received in the request.

I'm making the filter this way

```
let categories = req.body;
Product.find({ state: true, "category": {$in : categories} }...
```

This filter brings me the products that belong to a certain category but don't respect if the product has a state = true or false.

What I'm doing wrong?

Thx.

For example:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("601b9ef73faa662db0b29204"),
    "state" : true,
    "code" : "APE700JAGE",
    "category" : ObjectId("601b98853faa662db0b291e5"),
}

{
    "_id" : ObjectId("601b9ef73faa662db0b29204"),
    "state" : false,
    "code" : "PRU123FAKK",
    "category" : ObjectId("601b98853faa662db0b291e5"),
}
```

Request:

```
{
  categories: [ '601b98853faa662db0b291e5' ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are few fixes:

- you are passing whole `req.body` in categories variable, you just need to pass only `req.body.categories`

```
let categories = req.body.categories;
```

- the `categories` are array of string ids you need to convert it to object id using `mongoose.Types.ObjectId` because category is object id in document

```
let categories = req.body.categories.map(c => mongoose.Types.ObjectId(c));
```

Comment: Yes, but the problem is I'm getting products who has state = false, the filter of categories is working ok.

Comment: how it is working ok, how it will match category condition from object, second thing your query is good you just need to verify other things like database connection with correct server and collection name is correct or not.

Comment: I'm getting documents who has the right category, but the state of the documents is wrong, this brings me documents who has state = false, and I want only documents who has state = true

Comment: i got your point but the query is good see [playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/aCw5CkCA-Ph) you need to check other possibilities.